# Quotient group of $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^* / \{1,-1\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

What is the quotient group of $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^* / \{1,-1\}$ ?

If I take the usual decomposition via the Chinese remainder theorem of $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$ into a direct product of cyclic groups , unfortunately {-1,1} is not contained in any of the factors. I would hope that $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$ can be decomposed in a slightly different way containing $\{-1,1\} $ as one of the factors, but I am not sure about the details. It might be similar to the composition of the Klein'sche Vierergruppe in 2 different ways, like $V=(e,a)\times(e,b)=(e,ab)\times(e,b)$.

What I hope is to get statements like $(\mathbb{Z}/(4p)\mathbb{Z})^*/\{1,-1\} = C_{p-1}\times C_2/ \{1,-1\} = C_{p-1}$.

Comment: If $n$ has a primitive root, seems like it would be $C_{\phi(n)/2}$

Comment: In this case, $\{-1,1\} \subset  (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$, so this is the rather trivial case. Much more intesting is the situation where this is not the case.